# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Android 5, not in Android <=4

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

Just wondering why these differences in behaviour between Android 5 and any previous version. My app crashes on an Android 5 device with the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1291): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
```

Full:

```
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 1850
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850):     at com.example.myapp.MainActivity$CheckF.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:577)
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850):     at com.example.myapp.MainActivity$CheckF.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-26 15:14:30.629: E/AndroidRuntime(1850):     ... 4 more
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.myapp.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2b3f00e1 V.E..... R....... 0,0-772,296} that was originally added here
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at com.example.myapp.MainActivity$CheckF.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:519)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.buttonclick(MainActivity.java:130)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
05-26 15:14:31.658: E/WindowManager(1850):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

but works perfectly on Android 4 or older.

A strip of the code is something like this:

```
//selectedList.length is 3 and packages are 3
for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
                boolean selected=false;
                for(int i=0;i<selectedList.length;i++){
                    if(packageInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString().matches(selectedList[i])){
                        selected=true;
                    }
                }
                if(!selected){
                    //do stuff
                }
} //this is line 577 in the error log
```

Maybe worth to mention that selectedList[] is populated loading SharedPreferences. I checked and it's loaded correctly.
So how is it possible that only Android 5 fails with that error?

Comment: Please show the entire stack trace, and indicate what lines in the stack trace correspond to lines in your code snippet.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.

Comment: No, according to your code the length is 2

Comment: Try moving i++ around so it is within the actual loop

Comment: @TaylorCourtney: oops that was a typo, but made me re-check some other part of the code and I found the culprit, there was actually another array that caused that error.
Anyway the point is it's still strange the fact that Android <=4 was able to "ignore" that Exception, while Android 5 not, and without changing a single line of code...

Comment: Yes it is maybe submit a report?